# Leads/Lags in linear model with a subsample of the data frame in R

Tags: r, dataset, lag, linearmodels

I want to perform in R the next linear model:
\begin{equation}
lPC_t =  \beta_0 + \beta_1PIBtvh_{t+1} + \beta_2txDes_t + \beta_3Spread_{t+4} + u_t 
\end{equation}

---

The name of my data frame is Dados_R. I need to impose a restriction in the data once I want to estimate over just the observations between 19 and 45. The problem is that when I create the variables with the lead I cannot change the scope of them, or at least I cannot do it, unless I change the original data frame by myself what is not convenient once I want to perform more models with different leads.

So my question is how can I change the range of the variables that I created (leadPIBtvh0 e leadSpread0), in such a way that allows me to perform the linear model with just the observations between 19 and 45?

---

The code that I wrote:

```
attach(Dados_R)
leadPIBtvh0=lag(PIBtvh,1)
leadSpread0=lag(Spread,4)
data=Dados_R[19:45,]
detach(Dados_R)    
attach(data)
lPC=log(PC/(1-PC))
lm_lPC=lm(lPC~leadPIBtvh0+txDes+leadSpread0)
```

This code give me the error (that I understood):

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = lPC ~ leadPIBtvh0 + txDes + leadSpread0,  : : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'leadPIBtvh0')
```

Comment: Hi Fernando. It seems like you missed out the question. Please help to provide one?

Comment: Hi Jason. So my question is how can I change the range of the variables that I created (leadPIBtvh0 e leadSpread0), in such a way that allows me to perform the linear model with just the observations between 19 and 45?